# Trying to declare and initialize varible but it will lead to compilation fail

Tags: java, variables, instance, declaration

Trying to Declare Variable at class level that is instance variable but it is lead to compilation Error. Code is as follows,

```
class  Lab300{
     public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println(new Hello().a);
}
}
class Hello{
int a; 
a=10; }
```

Why This code showing  required Error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a new class which is instantiated (i.e. you use the new keyword) so you have to initialize in the constructor like so:

```
class Hello {
 public int a;
 public Hello(){
   a = 10;
 }
}
```

Or use an inline initializer:

```
  class Hello {
   public int a = 10;
  }
```

Comment: Or you can also use a code block with `{}` around initialization.. Like `{a = 10;}`

Comment: why can't we initialize it at second statement that is at second line?

Comment: True. I just put the most common ways to initialize to prevent confusion.

Comment: The class block is not code, it is a definition.  You define what will be part of the class.  Within the functions, inline code, and code blocks you can manipulate the values with statements. For instance the constructor (`public Hello()...`) runs any time you call `new Hello()`. You should read up on Classes in Java.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond Means that we can't code anything except Defining them..? Right?

Comment: No.  You can define a function and put code in there but it won't execute until you Instantiate an object and call the method (i.e. `new Hello().getA()`) or call a static method.